# EntityCommandExecutionException from Oracle database after period of inactivity

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am getting an Oracle database generated exception in my MVC application when it attempts to access the DB (via Entity Framework/DbContext) after a period of inactivity (~2 hours?). As a workaround I “catch” this exception and then repeat the query operation which then always succeeds. Here are the exception details:

```
ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error

Stack trace:
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(OracleTraceLevel level, OracleTraceTag tag, Exception ex)
   at OracleInternal.TTC.TTCExecuteSql.ReceiveExecuteResponse(Accessor[]& defineAccessors, Accessor[] bindAccessors, Boolean bHasReturningParams, SQLMetaData& sqlMetaData, SqlStatementType statementType, Int64 noOfRowsFetchedLastTime, Int32 noOfRowsToFetch, Int32& noOfRowsFetched, Int64& queryId, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 initialLOBFetchSize, Int64[] scnFromExecution, Boolean& bAllPureInputBinds, DataUnmarshaller& dataUnmarshaller, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper& marshalBindParamsHelper, Int64[]& rowsAffectedByArrayBind, Boolean bDefineDone, Boolean& bMoreThanOneRowAffectedByDmlWithRetClause, List`1& implicitRSList, Boolean bLOBArrayFetchRequired)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)

Inner:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Here is the code:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetSimpleItems()
{
    List<string> values;

    using (var db = new LLL_SST())
    {
        try
        {
            values = db.VW_SST_PLAN_RCPT_UNITS.Select(c => c.BUY_MODE).Distinct().ToList();

        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException ex)
        {
            //try again after db wakes up
            values = db.VW_SST_PLAN_RCPT_UNITS.Select(c => c.BUY_MODE).Distinct().ToList();
        }
    }

    return values;

}
```

There must be a config setting in Oracle that puts the listening process to sleep. Does anyone know what this is exactly? Any thoughts on a proper solution to deal with this?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Oracle itself will let an idle connection stay open indefinitely.  I'd wager that there is something in the network that is causing the error.  A firewall would be the most common culprit.

Comment: The best thing is that you find the problem (probably related to the network). Meanwhile you can work on Connection Pooling settings (i.e. disable it - discouraged - or you can drop a connection not used for a long time). You can find parameter about connection pooling here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/win.101/b10117/features001.htm